# Custom TextView can't set gravity

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, android-custom-view

I have a custom `TextView` that simply adds a dot to the left of the text, the color of the dot is determined by an internal state. However, the gravity cannot be set (whether in the view or xml) and the text overlaps with the dot, as you can see below (I set the background color to gray). The dimensions are correctly set though. Any idea on where the problem might be?

[image]

```
private var radius = 10.0f
private var newHeight = 0

override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        val radiusInPixel = Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, radius, resources.displayMetrics))
        val diameter = 2 * radiusInPixel
        newHeight = Math.max(measuredHeight, diameter)
        setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth + diameter + 30, newHeight)
    }

override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)

    paint.color = when (status) {
        Status.ACTIVE -> Color.GREEN
        else -> Color.TRANSPARENT
    }

    canvas.drawCircle(radius, newHeight / 2f + 3, radius, paint)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's probably due to the layout you are using, gravity work well with FrameLayout.
If you wanna add the ad the dot to the beggining of the text, I suggest you to use a LinearLayout as the parent of your text, and ad the dot as the first childof the view parent.

Comment: I am not using any layout, this is just a subclass of `TextView`